# Okular opens PDFs without colours

Tags: fedora, colors, pdf, okular

I am using okular on Fedora 31. Any pdf I open is opened without any colours!
It is grey colored. Any idea what causes this?

Comment: The KDE5 application `okular` is supposed to show colors. How about evince and atril ? ... Both available with # dnf install

Comment: i tried multiple pdf readers other than `okular` and all of them works well and colors are displayed. only  `okular` has this issue and I don't know why

Comment: Fedora 31 okular (installed today) : No color issues here. Your errors could be caused by a KDE5 or Qt5 flaw. Dependency list https://www.dropbox.com/s/wgalumegcnc3a0m/okular-fc31_depends-on.txt?dl=0

Comment: Try to remove the config and cache files for okular, or better create a new user and test from that user first.

Comment: @MunzirTaha I created another user and okular worked well! but I don't know how to clear the cache for my user? i found a folder in .cache dir in my home_dir, i deleted it but it did not effect, also tried to reinstall it but also did not effect.

any idea how to clear the cache my user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Settings -> Configure Okular... -> Defaults` to restore its settings to the defaults.

If this doesn't help, just remove the config and cache files of okular.

`rm -rf ~/.config/okular* ~/.local/share/okular/ ~/.cache/okular*`

You can also backup them up in case you need them later for comparison or restoring.

Comment: Great! restore defaults worked with me